# Is this the correct way to bulk INSERT ON CONFLICT in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert, upsert

I will provide a simplified example of my problem.

I have two tables: `reviews` and `users`.

`reviews` is updated with a bunch of reviews that users post. The process that fetches the reviews also returns information for the user that submitted it (and certain user data changes frequently).

I want to update `users` whenever I update `reviews`, in bulk, using `COPY`. The issue arises for `users` when the fetched data contains two or more reviews from the same user. If I do a simple `INSERT ON CONFLICT`, I might end up with errors since and `INSERT` statement cannot update the same row twice.

A `SELECT DISTINCT` would solve that problem, but I also want to guarantee that I insert the latest data into the `users` table. This is how I am doing it. Keep in mind I am doing this in bulk:

**1. Create a temporary table so that we can `COPY` to/from it.**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE users_temp (
    id uuid, 
    stat_1 integer, 
    stat_2 integer, 
    account_age_in_mins integer);
```

**2. `COPY` data into temporary table**

```
COPY users_temp (
    id,
    stat_1,
    stat_2,
    account_age_in_mins) FROM STDIN CSV ENCODING 'utf-8';
```

**3. Lock `users` table and perform `INSERT ON CONFLICT`**

```
LOCK TABLE users in EXCLUSIVE MODE;

INSERT INTO users SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) 
    users_temp.id,
    users_temp.stat_1,
    users_temp.stat_2,
    users_temp.account_age_in_mins
FROM users_temp
ORDER BY 1, 4 DESC, 2, 3
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET
    stat_1 = EXCLUDED.stat_1,
    stat_2 = EXCLUDED.stat_2,
    account_age_in_mins = EXCLUDED.account_age_in_mins';
```

The reason I am doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` and an `ORDER BY` in step **3)** is because I:

1. Only want to return one instance of the duplicated rows.
2. From those
   duplicates make sure that I get the most up to date record by
   sorting on the `account_age_in_mins`.

**Is this the correct method to achieve my goal?**

Comment: Looks pretty ok.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Good to hear. Anything you'd do differently?

Comment: At first glance, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very good approach.
Maybe you can avoid the table-lock, when you lock only tuples you have in your temporary table.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106121/locking-in-postgres-for-update-insert-combination